# I want the edit.php page to not give me any errors

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello guys I found an awesome CRUD file for updating to a sql database with php every thing works great but the thing that is very annoying is that the index.php page haves a button that links to edit.php?post_id= so that's correct, but any ways I like to test pages because I know there is going to be a boring illogical person that will say to them self's what would happen if I do this etc.. any ways so what I did instead of putting edit.php?post_id= and the id of a post from my mysqli database in the url I instead put this in the url as simply as edit.php and it said this error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in etc.. on line 43 so basically I just want to fix this edit.php page when some one types this directly and what I mean by fixing this is I want no errors shown when some one types www.example.com/edit.php since www.example.com/edit.php?post_id= shows no errors.

Here's what I mean

visually

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Jvn.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k00xV.png)

and the code

```
<?php

include("/fake_path/instructions/php/session_and_connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   

$post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['post_id']);

$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$topic_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['topic_id']);
$post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['post_title']);
$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['post_content']);


// checking empty fields
if(empty($post_title) || empty($post_content)) {    

if(empty($post_title)) {
echo "<font color='red'>post_title field is empty.</font><br/>";
}

if(empty($post_content)) {
echo "<font color='red'>post_content field is empty.</font><br/>";
}

} else {    
//updating the table
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE posts SET user_id='$user_id',topic_id='$topic_id',post_title='$post_title',post_content='$post_content' WHERE post_id=$post_id");

//redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
header("Location: index.php");
}
}
?>
<?php
//getting post_id from url
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

//selecting data associated with this particular post_id
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=$post_id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$user_id = $res['user_id'];
$topic_id = $res['topic_id'];
$post_title = $res['post_title'];
$post_content = $res['post_content'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>  
<title>Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<br/><br/>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
<table border="0">
<tr> 
<td>post_title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $post_title;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>post_content</td>
<td><input type="text" name="post_content" value="<?php echo $post_content;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="post_id" value=<?php echo $_GET['post_id'];?>></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't call the SQL whilst `$post_id` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a post_id then why don't you update the db query to : 
`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=$post_id` to `SELECT * FROM posts` and remove the lines 36 and 37 i.e.

```
//getting post_id from url
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
```

Comment: Well I did what you suggested. But it gave me strange results in other words so when I went directly to the page it had a random info from the data base and the info stayed the same even when I try to edit other info. So yeah it did not work how I wanted it to work like.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to remove the `post_id`. For normal crud operations it is required to identify a record from database and thus enables us to update the record later.

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** use `exit()` after `header()` function

```
header("Location: index.php"); exit();
```

**2nd :** you should not run the query when get parameter is empty so use `isset` and `!empty()` like below .

```
if(!empty($_GET['post_id '])) {

    //getting post_id from url
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    .......

    </html>
}
```

**3rd :** Set get parameter again in submit url so that if any field is empty means it will echo the value and also fetch the data from database using `$_GET['post_id']` this id again .

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php<?php if(isset($_GET['post_id'])){ echo '?post_id='.$_GET['post_id']; ?>">
```

**4th :** Try to use `prepared statement or pdo` to avaoid sql injection

**5th :** No need to while loop for single row record set .

Comment: You don't need both, `!empty()` is all you need ;-)

Comment: I did what you suggested but now I get the same error I got before.